# With WooCommerce update, woocommerce_before_checkout_form hook is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to show "Hellos!" on the checkout page but in the update WP it's not working. That means I can't see anything to add this code on the checkout page:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Text check
Description: Display a custom button on the WooCommerce checkout page.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'ts_before_checkout_form', 10 );
function ts_before_checkout_form($product_Id){
echo "hellos";
}
```

Comment: If your theme or yourself is using WooCommerce checkout Gutenberg Block, the hook `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` won't work. Also it may not work in some themes customizing WooCommerce checkout templates…

Comment: try `return 'hellos';` instead of `echo "hellos";`

Comment: i's not working. If you know give me the correct solution.